# Is it possible to do a "field IN list" query in JDBC, with the list passed as a parameter?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to run a query of the type "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)" using a prepared statement. I tried a couple of ways to pass the list as a parameter, but it didn't work: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1". I'm using PostgreSQL.

The only way that works so far is "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?)" with each value as a separate parameter. Is it possible to pass the list directly as a single parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass the list directly as a single parameter?

No, it's not possible. You need to bind each parameter separately.

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible, if you will use [Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause).